# A function that two (pos) integers k and n , and 1. prints all increasing sequences of length k of the numbers 1-.n 2. returns the number sequences

Tags: c, recursion

Here is the full question:

Question 3 [30 points].
Write a function that two positive integers k and n , and works as follows
1. prints all increasing sequences of length k consisting of the numbers 1...n
2. returns the number of such sequences. For example

```
int print_k_sequences( int n, int k)
For example, print_k_sequences( 5 , 3) prints the following sequences
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 4 5
2 3 4
2 3 5
2 4 5
3 4 5
and returns 10
```

The specific order in which the sequences are printed is up to you. Add exactly one space
between numbers. Don’t forget to separate the sequences with new lines.
Your function should work in reasonable time on inputs n,k up to 20.
[Hint: use recursion. You may also want to use a helper function]

my implementation that only prints the first sequence and then stops. where am I going wrong?

```
//helper for printing array
void printArr( int arr[], int size){

    for(int i =0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arr[i] );
    }
    printf("\n");

    return;
}

int findSeq ( int arr[], int n, int k){

/* start from last index and find first elelment less than n if righmost element
is n then we have to incremenet arr value with 1 at starting index*/
    int p = k -1;
    while(arr[p == n])
    {
        p=0;
    }

    //  if the last element is the n and the difference of n and k is one greater
    // thant the first elelment that means last sequence is generated
    if(arr[k-1] ==n && (n-k) == arr[0]-1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    /* else increase the value of array element till n*/
    arr[p] = arr[p] + 1;

    /* the nextr index value of array shoul always be greater than previous value */
    for (int i = p+1; i<k; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i-1] +1;
    }

    return 1;

}

int print_k_sequences(int n,int k) {
  // implement me

    int arr[k];

    int count = 0;

    /*values of first seq*/
    while (1){
        printArr(arr, k);

        count++;

        if(findSeq(arr, n, k) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

  return count;
}
```

This is the code that tests it: note none of the parameters of the primary function can be changed.

```
bool test_q3_1()  {
  int ans = print_k_sequences(6, 2);
  if (ans == 15)  {
    // need to also check the actual sequences
    printf("Q3-1 ok\n");
    return true;
  }
  else  {
    printf("Q3-2 ERROR: answer=%d, correct=15 \n", ans);
    return false;
  }
}

bool test_q3_2()  {
  int ans = print_k_sequences(8, 3);
  if (ans == 56)  {
    // need to also check the actual sequences
    printf("Q3-2 ok\n");
    return true;
  }
  else  {
    printf("Q3-2 ERROR: answer=%d, correct=56 \n", ans);
    return false;
  }
}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out :)

for anyone coming accross this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int numberOfSequences; // global variable to count number of sequences generated

// function to print contents of arr[0..k-1]
void OutputSequence(int arr[], int k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

// function to generate all increasing sequences from 1..n of length k
void generateSequence(int n, int k, int *len, int arr[]) {

    // If length of the array sequence becomes k
    if (*len == k) {
        numberOfSequences++; // we increment the counter by 1
        OutputSequence(arr, k); // and print that sequence
        return;
    }

    int i;
    // If length is 0, then start putting new numbers in the sequence from 1.
    // If length is not 0, then start from previous element +1.
    if (*len == 0)
        i = 1;
    else
        i = arr[*len - 1] + 1;

    // Increase length of the sequence so far
    (*len)++;

    // Put all numbers (which are greater than the previous element) at new position.
    while (i <= n) {
        arr[(*len) - 1] = i;    // adding the new element to the sequence
        generateSequence(n, k, len, arr);// generating the subsequent elements in the sequence
        i++;
    }

    (*len)--;
}

// driver function to print all increasing sequences from 1..n of length k
// and return the number of such sequences
int print_k_sequences(int n, int k) {
    int arr[k]; // array to store individual sequences
    int len = 0; // Initial length of current sequence
    numberOfSequences = 0; // counter to count number of sequences
    generateSequence(n, k, &len, arr);
    return numberOfSequences;
}

int main() {
    int k = 3, n = 5;
    printf("The sequences between 1.. %d  of length %d are:\n", n, k);
    int ans = print_k_sequences(n, k);
    printf("No of sequences= %d\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the test code that checks in automated manner for any n,k the sequence. In fact, you have stated that ordering does not matter. Then, need something to store all partial sequences, say those starting with 1, etc.